# Run CGI on page load

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

Following is what I want to accomplish:

- In the html When the page loads(onload) I want to run a CGI script which is a C program to run a function in it.

I am thinking of calling a JS function onload in html:

```
<body onload="MyJsFunc();">
```

then in the JS file:

```
function MyJsFunc()  
{  
    //call MyCGIfunc()  
}
```

Now, how do I call my cgi above?

I am not sure if what I am trying to accomplish is doable or not.

Note: I cant use jquery

Answer (score 0):

CGI programs are executed by making an HTTP request to them.

If you want to trigger them when a page is loaded, then the usual approach is to have the page be generated from the CGI program in the first place.

Failing that, you can use a [Server Side Include](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml) to call the CGI program. (Note: You need to have your server configured to parse your HTML document for SSI directives).

```
<!--#exec cmd="./my_cgi" -->
```

If you really want to use JavaScript, then you will have to make the browser issue an additional HTTP request. This is usually done using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object.

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/my_cgi");
myReqest.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe to exec cgi. as :

```
<iframe src="/cgi-bin/script.cgi" width="300" height="150">
```